# Can Syrian citizens transit the Schengen area without a visa?

Tags: visas, transit, airport-transfer, klm, syrian-citizens

I have a plan to travel from Doha to Moscow using KLM airlines with transit 2 hrs in Amsterdam, the Russian embassy has already issued a tourist visa and posted it on my passport.

My question, since I'm a Syrian citizen has resident permit in Qatar. Do you think I will face any issue or refused boarding by the airline at Qatar or while transferring planes in Amsterdam since the 2Hrs transit will be in Schengen area and my previous Schengen visa  is already expired??.

Please consider that the Syrian citizens has different consideration than any other nationalities in the airports, because of the civil war situation.

Comment: @Calchas even when using the transfer area, ie "remaining airside", [certain nationals require an airport transit visa (ATV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Airport_transit). This currently includes Syrians transiting in the Netherlands.

Comment: @krubo Agreed. Comment withdrawn.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Timatic](https://www.klm.com/travel/qa_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/timatic.htm) you will need a transit visa:

> National Syria (SY)             /Residence Qatar (QA) Embarkation
>   Qatar (QA)          /Transit Netherlands (NL) Destination Russian Fed.
>   (RU)    ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW
>
> Netherlands (NL)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Visa required, except for Nationals of
>   Syria, holding onward
>
> tickets transiting For details, click here by the same or first
>   connecting aircraft **AND** meeting one of the following
>
> conditions:
>
> - holding a valid visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia,
>
>   Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania, USA or United    Kingdom,
>     traveling to any non-Schengen Member State;
>
>   - WARNING: TWOV is not possible when arriving from a   non-Schengen Member State AND departing to a Schengen Member

So you need to visit the Netherland's embassy and apply for a transit visa.